# Error while parsing TeamCity service message

Tags: .net, testing, teamcity

When running a TC build with playwright tests, the test do pass, however at the end of step `dotnet test` I keep getting a following error:

`Tests passed: 102, ignored: 1; failed to publish artifacts: Failed to upload artifact, error: java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect (new)`

when digging into build log it looks like snippet below(some data has been removed), but **fullyQualifiedName** somehow is missing closing apostrophe and I suspect this causes error.

```
Publishing artifacts
  Collecting files to publish: [E:\BuildAgent\work\...] => .teamcity/VSTest/Autom
  ##teamcity[testFinished name='TestName' duration='44' ...
  fullyQualifiedName='AutomationTestService...]
  Error while parsing TeamCity service message: 
  Value should end with "'". 
  Valid service message has a form of "##teamcity[messageName name1='escaped_value' name2='escaped_value']" where escaped_value uses substitutions: '->|', [->|[, ]->|], |->||, newline->|n
```

In build configuration I use simple:
**Runner type: .Net**
*Command: test*

I have checked the **Configuration Parameters** and this *fullyQualifiedName* isn't listed there. Any idea what can be the root of the problem? How can I change it?